# Error when trying to run method

Tags: c#

I have made this program and I dont know how to make it run. I usualy run my methods inside the 2 big methods that I have `button1_Click` (`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`)  and `button2_Click`  (`private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`).

**I write `this.Lista();` in the button1_Click method and it gives me the error: *No overload for method 'Lista' takes 0 arguments.***

```
public void Lista(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] col2 = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

            if (col2[i] == "Browse From File...")
            {
                DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
                if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                   // filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of your code, `public void Lista(object sender, EventArgs e)` states that the method expects the parameters in the brackets.

So you should remove the parameters from `Lista(object sender, EventArgs e)` (because i see you don't use them in the method anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide `sender` and `e`. Or define it as

```
public void Lista()
{
    string[] col2 = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

            if (col2[i] == "Browse From File...")
            {
                DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
                if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                   // filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method with the correct parameters!

Your signature is:

```
public void Lista(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

So you must call it with the required parameters, such as:

```
Lista(this,EventArgs.Empty);
```

You could remove the parameters completely from your method, they are probably unneeded. You could also set up Button1 to call Lista directly, rather than using the default click handler to call this method.